# python code is slower after a multiprocessing-function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm calculating a complicated one, and some procedure of this function is slow. So I used Fortran and multiprocessing together to speed up my code.

For example, this function (without multiprocessing) looks like this:

```py
from fortran_module import fortran_func1, fortran_func2

def test():
    # some codes...   [A]

    res1 = fortran_func1(...)

    # some codes...   [B]
    
    res2 = fortran_func2(res1, ...)

    return res2
```

The `fortran_module` is compiled from `f2py`.

And if I used `line_profiler` to analysis this code, it told me that codes of part `[A]` cost 100 ms, `fortran_func1` cost 300000 ms, `[B]` cost 1000 ms, and `fortran_func2` cost 100000ms.

I want to speed up `fortran_func1`, so I rewrote it (original version is calculated in a 3-dimensional space, and the new version is calculated only in 2-dimensional space), and together with multiprocessing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from fortran_module import fortran_func1_new, fortran_func2

def fortran_func1_new_wrapper(...):
    """in order to make it picklable, so can be used in multiprocessing"""
    return fortran_func1_new(...)

def func1_pool(...):
    args = ...    # create a list of `fortran_func1_wrapper` arguments
    pool = Pool()
    res_list = pool.starmap(fortran_func1_new_wrapper, args)
    return np.stack(res_list, axis=-1)

def test():
    # some codes...   [A]             # -- speed of this part doesn't change

    res1 = func1_pool(...)            # -- speed of this is FASTER comparing to the old version

    # some codes...   [B]             # -- speed of this part is SLOWER than the old version
    
    res2 = fortran_func2(res1, ...)   # -- speed of this is SLOWER than the old version

    return res2
```

The result is identical to the previous one. But `line_profiler` told me something weird. In this new version, the codes of part `[A]` cost nearly 100 ms, `func1_pool` cost 200000 ms, `[B]` cost 2000 ms, and `fortran_func2` cost 200000ms.

In other words, although the speed of `func1_pool` is faster than the old version, ALL codes AFTER `func_pool` is **SLOWER** than the old version. And all codes after `func1_pool` is exactly same to the old version.

I'm not familiar with `multiprocessing`. Does anyone know what is happened? `func1_pool` faster than the old version is expected behavior, but why the codes after `func1_pool` is slower? And how can I avoid this problem?

Very thanks!

Comment: The gain in processing depends upon what you are trying to do within these functions.. If the functions are IO intensive then multiprocessing will not add any benefits.. Multithreading itself is sufficient.. Only if the tasks which you are trying to run parallely are CPU intensive you will see a difference. the degradation may be because of the overhead involved in creating new processes and managing them..

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran it is reverse: if functions are IO intensive, both multithreading and multiprocessing will be faster. In CPU instensive workloads multithreading will be limited by GIL but multiprocessing will be able to parallelize, although with some penalty for marshalling (overhead to create processes is usually negligible)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My functions are CPU intensive. And the problem is not the paralleized-function is slower, but the codes AFTER paralleized-function is slower.... I have no idea why.